# Running Frank on Device

Tags: ios, testing, frank

I am stuck on getting a Frankified.app running on a device.  When I do step 1 on the [online tutorial](http://testingwithfrank.com/device.html):

xcodebuild -target Frank-Fruitstrap -xcconfig ./Frank/frankify.xcconfig -arch arm7 -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=YES DSTROOT="~/Documents/Workspace/Frank-Fruitstrap/Frank/frankified_build/" FRANK_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS="~/Documents/Workspace/Frank-Fruitstrap/Frank" clean build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY='iPhone Developer: '

and I get this:

** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET Frank-Fruitstrap OF PROJECT Frank-Fruitstrap WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm7, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s).

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)

The codesign works for other apps when I run them from command line, just not a Frankified app.

Am I the only one who has problems with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from Pete Hodgeson on this.  Here is the post on [this google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/frank-discuss/GHgxxJWAs4I)

This is what Pete Suggested for me:

`This is a fairly common project setting issue I think. You should be able to resolve it by modifying the build settings for your Frank-Fruitstrap target. Either change "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No", or add "arm7" to the "Valid Architectures" list.`

I did the latter and it worked.